# GeoServer updated 2.22.0 to 2.23.1 WMS GetCapabilities Translator Error

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

GeoServer updated from 2.22.0 to 2.23.1 and now WMS GetCapabilities shows translator error.

WFS and WMTS getCapabilies work without any errors.

WMS GetCapabilities document works in QGIS if given username and password, but not with authkey or without any authentication. Authkey module installed also.

**EDIT:** Admin user can see the capabilities document with username and password or authkey. There is atleast one other user who can see capabilities document. Will look into why, but most user cannot see anything.

**EDIT2:** Catalog Mode Challenge works, but not hide or mixed. We normally use mixed.

I don't know if we missed some step in GeoServer installation, but where should we look for a solution?

GetCapabilities error:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc https://[redacted]/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
<ServiceException> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Translator error Translator error class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58 cannot be cast to class org.geoserver.catalog.LayerInfo (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58 and org.geoserver.catalog.LayerInfo are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @4f0f2942) </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

And GeoServer logs:

```
2023-07-04 17:58:37,055 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Translator error
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.write(Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.java:45) ~[gs-wms-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.config.CapabilitiesCacheHeadersCallback$RevalidateTagResponse.write(CapabilitiesCacheHeadersCallback.java:138) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018) ~[gs-ows-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272) ~[gs-ows-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656) ~[?:?]
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.flow.controller.IpBlacklistFilter.doFilter(IpBlacklistFilter.java:89) ~[gs-control-flow-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.flow.ControlFlowCallback.doFilter(ControlFlowCallback.java:264) ~[gs-control-flow-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39) ~[gs-platform-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerAuthenticationKeyFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAuthenticationKeyFilter.java:100) ~[gs-authkey-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.8.jar:5.7.8]
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:319) ~[jetty-servlets-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:273) ~[jetty-servlets-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Translator error
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:125) ~[gt-xml-29.1.jar:?]
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:103) ~[gt-xml-29.1.jar:?]
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.write(Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.java:43) ~[gs-wms-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    ... 125 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58 cannot be cast to class org.geoserver.catalog.LayerInfo (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58 and org.geoserver.catalog.LayerInfo are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @4f0f2942)
    at org.geoserver.security.impl.DefaultResourceAccessManager.buildInFunctionResourceFilter(DefaultResourceAccessManager.java:710) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.impl.DefaultResourceAccessManager.getSecurityFilter(DefaultResourceAccessManager.java:562) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.CatalogFilterAccessManager.getSecurityFilter(CatalogFilterAccessManager.java:178) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.securityFilter(SecureCatalogImpl.java:1721) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.list(SecureCatalogImpl.java:1627) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractFilteredCatalog.list(AbstractFilteredCatalog.java:933) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.list(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:588) ~[gs-main-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.getLayers(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:349) ~[gs-wms-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.encode(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:303) ~[gs-wms-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$XMLReaderSupport.parse(TransformerBase.java:1054) ~[gt-xml-29.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485) ~[xalan-2.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$Task.run(TransformerBase.java:287) ~[gt-xml-29.1.jar:?]
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:121) ~[gt-xml-29.1.jar:?]
    at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:103) ~[gt-xml-29.1.jar:?]
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.write(Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.java:43) ~[gs-wms-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    ... 125 more
```

Comment: did you upgrade Java from 1.8 to 17 by any chance?

Comment: @IanTurton No, we didn't do any changes to Java or actually anything else between these installs. Java is 11.

Comment: Problem seems to be about layer groups and data security being broken. Layer groups that are part of a workspace and have a data security role assigned to them. To be fixed in GeoServer 2.23.2.  https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10997